# Extract data from HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code generates an html table from json. I control 100% of the code. It can be any format with the limitation that the final code work in IE8 using simple jquery and javascript. I want my users to be able to edit data in the table. After edit AJAX sends the changes to the server. I need help figuring out how to get data from the table.

I've tried these approaches:
1. Generate function calls when the table is created and click a button to edit. Basically create populate function calls with table data when the table is generated.
2. My second approach is close to 1, but I try to limit the number of parameters in the pre-populated function calls by 'hiding' data in each element. For some reason I can only get this to work if something like this is embedded in each td element:

```
<td><input type="hidden" value="foo" id ="fooId"/>foo</td>
```

But this approach basically stores the data twice. I can extract the data with jquery like so:

```
document.getElementById(fooId).value
```

Below there is some sample code where I try to illustrate my two approaches and a third that I guess I wish would work but doesn't. My ultimate goal is a button in the third row that, when clicked, combines data from the other rows in the column.

Is there a simpler way to do this that will work with IE8? I really don't like having all this hidden html in my code and it seems likely there is a better way. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Matt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <script>

        function functionCallAndTableGeneratedAtSameTime(row, col) {
            alert('Function call generated with table: row:'+row + ' col:' + col);
        }

        function functionExtractsDataFromHiddenInputElement(inId) {
            var myData ='Function call extracts data from hidden input element:' + document.getElementById(inId).value;
            alert(myData);
        }

        function viewContentsByTdId(inId) {
            var myNewTitle = document.getElementById(inId).value;
            alert(myNewTitle);
        }



    </script>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">Extract Table Data</h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1<input type="submit" id="byBtn11" value="FunctionCallAndTableGeneratedAtSameTime" onclick="functionCallAndTableGeneratedAtSameTime('1', '1')"/></td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2<input type="submit" id="byBtn12" value="FunctionCallAndTableGeneratedAtSameTime" onclick="functionCallAndTableGeneratedAtSameTime('1', '2')"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="Submit5" value="Do Something With Combined Row1Col1 and Row1Col2 Data" onclick="functionCallAndTableGeneratedAtSameTime('col1', 'col2')"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td><input type="hidden" value="row 1, cell 2" id ="r2c1"/>row 2, cell 1<input type="submit" id="Submit2" value="FunctionExtractsDataFromHiddenInputElement" onclick="functionExtractsDataFromHiddenInputElement('r2c1')"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" value="row 1, cell 2" id ="r2c2"/>row 2, cell 2<input type="submit" id="Submit3" value="FunctionExtractsDataFromHiddenInputElement" onclick="functionExtractsDataFromHiddenInputElement('r2c2')"/></td>
<td><input type="submit" id="Submit6" value="Do Something With Combined Row1Col1 and Row1Col2 Data" onclick="functionExtractsDataFromHiddenInputElement('row2')"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td id="r3c1">row 3, cell 1<input type="submit" id="Submit1" value="ViewContentsByTdID (DoesNotWork)" onclick="viewContentsByTdId('r3c1')"/></td>
    <td id="r3c2">row 3, cell 2<input type="submit" id="Submit4" value="ViewContentsByTdID (DoesNotWork)" onclick="viewContentsByTdId('r3c1')"/></td>
    <td id="r3c3"><input type="submit" id="Submit7" value="Do Something With Combined Row3Col1 and Row3Col2 Data" onclick="viewContentsByTdId('r3')"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer to my question: all methods ought to work. There is an error in the id tags and I was creating the event handlers before the html was generated. Something of a train wreck! Sorry!

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, please post the solution as an answer, and mark it as correct.